# Populating asp.net form from drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net

My Selected Index Changed from my drop down list, displays my list items, but will only display the top list item when any of the list items are selected to populate the form. It was working fine earlier today (perhaps I have changed something without noticing) and now it does not work.

```
 protected void ddlEdit_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Book b = catalogueInstance.books[ddlEdit.SelectedIndex];
    txtID.Text = b.id.ToString();
    txtTitle.Text = b.title;
    txtAuthor.Text = b.author;
    txtYear.Text = b.year.ToString();
    txtPublisher.Text = b.publisher;
    txtISBN.Text = b.isbn;
}
```

Comment: if this code hasn’t changed, it should work. What other changes did you do?

Comment: And what doesn’t work?

Comment: Nothing really, made some c# changes to other pages but I have rversed them just incase it affected this somehow

Comment: When the drop down list displays the list items (books in a catalogue) Say I select the 4th item down to populate the form fields, it will only populate the foem with the values of the first item in the list (book).

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your method and check the value of `ddlEdit.SelectedIndex`

Comment: when I set AppendDataBoundItems to "True", it will populate the fields with my selection, but I did not have this set today. Weird. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If i was to guess this--You must be binding the DropDownList in the Page_Load event. Wrap that code inside Page.IsPostBack Check like below.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {

      DropDownListBind();//here goes your binding code
   }
```